# LG - REVERE Contacts transfer

Tags: export, contacts, mobile-phone

I would like to transfer contact from 
VERIZON LG-VN150 REVERE to my OUTLOOK contacts.

Is there any solution for this, beside manual contact transfer.

I tried to connect the phone to PC via cable, but there is no genuine(LG) software for this phone, therefore I can't access any data on the phone.

Also, I tried using DataPilot, but I was only able to access pictures and videos.

I need a solution to export contacts from VERIZON LG-VN150 REVERE to PC.

Comment: Beside(s) what?  What have you tried already?  Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this model supports transferring contacts via Bluetooth, and you have a Bluetooth adapter for your PC, you could transfer them there, and then convert them to a format Outlook wants (.vcf, I believe).

On feature phones such as the one you have, the contacts are not designed to be extractible by the consumer.  There is no way to download them directly to Outlook.

The easiest thing to do will be to visit a local store of your carrier, they will have a machine called a "Cellebrite" which can extract them (usually they can email or copy to a flash drive) or print them out.

The BitPim project has reversed engineered the proprietary protocol of many feature phones, and you could use this if you had the correct cable (often a Cellebrite-compatible cable), and could manage to find the drivers for it (note that some Cellebrite cables look like standard USB cables but aren't).  I am not seeing your model in the supported models list (http://www.bitpim.org/help/) so unfortunately this won't help.

Comment: I transferred contacts to Samsung smartphone and then to pc... Thank you!